# Data bound ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, contextmenu

I need to implement a contextMenu bound to a collection returned from a web service.
The data returned is a collection of the ContextMenuModel class:

```
List<ContextMenuItem> menuItems = webService.GetMenuItemsForUser(userID);

public class ContextMenuItem
{        
    public string MainItemName { get; set; }
    public List<ContextSubItem> SubItems { get; set; }

    public ContextMenuItem()
    {
        SubItems = new List<ContextSubItem>();
    }
}

public class ContextSubItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How would I bind that class on a ContextMenu? Particularly, how would I bind the subitems to a contextMenu?

**EDIT**

I've tried the following but the subItems don't expand. If I explicitly set `IsSubmenuOpen` to the mainItem datatemplate, they are visible, but once closed, they don't show again on a second attempt.

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
        <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding MainItemName}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}" >
                    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                </MenuItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>                                                
    </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`HierarchicalDataTemplate`** in case you want nested collection:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding MainItemName}"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the bindings here. The name property of the subitem is not recognized in the second hierarhical template. Is this a correct structure of the templates?

Comment: SubItem has property Name to which you bind to because that's what you mentioned in the question as well. And yes this is the correct structure. Works fine at my end.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I was accidentally setting the HeaderTemplate. Blame intellisense for that. Thanks!